# No route matches [POST] for ajax json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, routes

Mu current routes for groups are:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :links # Enables group/:id/link/new
  collection do
    post 'order_links'
  end 
  # I tried adding: 
  # collection do
  #   post 'show'
  # end
end
```

How do I add a 'POST" route for show so that a json show request can be used?

I tried just `get 'show'`, i.e.

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :links # Enables group/:id/link/new
    collection do
      post 'order_links'
    end
    get 'show'
  end
```

but I get

```
Error loading: <!DOCTYPE html>
...
<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>No route matches [POST] &quot;/groups/42&quot;</pre></p>
<p>
```

Comment: what route you exactly want to make? and why a post route for show action?

Comment: I want to make an ajax call and examples seem to want a post route (see error).  Is it ok to use get if I am only requesting data ?

Comment: you are just `fetching` the data from database , you are free to use `get`, actually this is what `get` request is typically designed for.

Comment: yeah, ok I changed the ajax call to be GET, i.e. `$.ajax({type: "GET"`,
 instead of `$.ajax({type: "POST"` and that fixed it.
`

Comment: feel free to post that as an answer Mandeep or Paritosh. It helped me find it.

Comment: added. the first answer seems to be useless. but thats the original answer of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resourceful**

Michael, perhaps you'd be better suited to using the standard CRUD actions as defined in the Rails [resourceful routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

[image]

As demonstrated, you have a `GET` show action by convention, meaning you can use this route with the corresponding [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block, to define the response for JSON:

```
#app/controllers/groups_controller.rb
Class GroupsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @group = Group.find params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @group.to_json }
      end
   end
end
```

- I don't know what you want to perform with this - so I've just posted the `@group` variable to your JSON request

--

**Mime Types**

I think you're getting confused with the role of `mime types` with Rails

Your `controller#actions` are not restricted to your [`mime types`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) directly. The mime types are just a way to determine the *type* of request being sent, not which action is going to process it

Therefore, you may be better suited to sending the request to a controller you already have in your system (by virtue of the `resources` directive), and then determine the response based on the mime type (in your case JSON).

You can do this by handling the request as so:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.ajax({
   url: "groups/" + $(this).attr("href"),
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
resources :groups do
    resources :links # Enables group/:id/link/new
    collection do
      post 'order_links'
      post 'show'
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make an ajax call and examples seem to want a post route (see error). Is it ok to use get if I am only requesting data ?

if you are just fetching the data from database , you are free to use `get`, actually this is what `get` request is typically designed for.